# Multiple htaccess rewrites with subdomains & execptions

Tags: php, web-services, .htaccess, redirect, apache2

I have a complicated set of rewrite rules that I'm trying to simplify but keep ending up in a corner. My objectives are as follows:

1. Redirect all traffic to website through www (except subdomains 'test' and 'dev')
2. Redirect all traffic through https
3. Redirect all traffic through a particular directory ('webservice') through a file within that directory, using url strings as parameters

So far I have 2 htaccess files, one in my web root and the other in my webservice directory.

My root htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Ensure www on all URLs.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(dev|test)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Ensure we are using HTTPS version of the site.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(dev|test)\. [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(webservice)/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

So far this works fine and redirects most of my traffic correctly through www and https.

My second htaccess file looks like this in /webservice/rest :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /webservice/rest
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?(\?([\w-=?&]))?$ api_client.php?method=$1&params=$2 [L,NC]
```

This correctly redirects my url based api parameters into the correct file within /webservice/rest ('api_client').

This is as close to a final solution that I've managed to get. The remaining problem is that urls that are directed to the 'webservice' url are not redirected to www or https (I also wish to NOT redirect 'test' and 'dev' subdmains that point to the /webservice/rest folder as exceptions)

Any ideas how to do this whilst maintaining my final webservice htaccess parameter redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the same www/https redirects in the htaccess file of the subdirectory, because it supercedes the rules in the parent directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /webservice/rest

# Ensure www on all URLs.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(dev|test)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?(\?([\w-=?&]))?$ api_client.php?method=$1&params=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon - this is closer but not quite there. If I make this change I have to uncomment that line in my first code block - "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(webservice)/" and it all NEARLY hangs together, except when I request an API starting with simply example.com (rather than www) my very last rewrite rule does not execute the parameters correctly - final product looks like https://www.example.com/webservice/rest/api_client.php?method=exampleMethod&params=

Comment: Also - I have to uncomment that line in my first code block otherwise I get redirected to 404

Comment: Scratch that Jon - this worked for me, must have just taken a few minutes to fully propogate.
For anyone else who stumbles across this, I needed to exclude my subdirectory using RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(webservice)/ for this to work, as well as add all my riles to the second htaccess file - perhaps someone else could shed light as to why